# Getting rid of the "Enter password" message in sqlplus results?

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, command-line, sqlplus

This is probably a very silly question, but here it goes...

This is my syntax for getting some data using sqlplus in Unix command line:

```
echo pwd|sqlplus -S -L user@db @mysqlfile >> otherfile
```

It works OK, but 'otherfile' starts with the line 'Enter password:', which is pretty annoying, and it makes for extra code for parsing results. So the question is:

How do I get rid of the 'Enter password:' line? Am I doing something wrong there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you pass the connect command to the `sqlplus`, along with the script you want to execute. You'll also have to utilize the `/nolog` and `-S` (silent) options:

```
[oracle@localhost]$ cat mysqlfile.sql 
select * from dual;
[oracle@localhost]$ (echo connect username/secretpassword ; echo @mysqlfile) | sqlplus -S /nolog >> out
[oracle@localhost]$ cat out

D
-
X

[oracle@localhost]$
```

Edit:
Using your parameters:

```
(echo connect user/pwd ; echo @mysqlfile) | sqlplus -S /nolog >> otherfile
```

Comment: Right, thanks... I have a doubt about your answer, tho. [oracle@localhost]$ there stands for the regular Unix command line, or does that work only if already logged to sqlplus? Also, if it is the command line, I'm not getting what hr/oracle stands for there... again, sorry if this is too obvious, I just got tasked with these scripts and never used sqlplus before...

Comment: @dumber_than_thou In this context, `hr/oracle` means `username/password`.

Comment: @dumber_than_thou No problem, let me explain: `username` is the `user` from your piece of code, and `secretpassword` is `pwd` from your example. My solution works right from the Linux command line, no need to be connected to Oracle. Just try my example with parameters from your script and check out if it works for you.

Comment: I hope nobody performs `ps -ef` and sees the pwd. When that's a problem consider a "here-document".

Comment: @WalterA he could do something like sqlplus -s $LOGON << eof
/@mysqlfile
exit;
eof
Where $LOGON is sourced from a dot file containing LOGON=user/pass

Comment: Excellent, thanks! And the password gets sourced from a Java encryptor, so no trouble with that... thank you very much.

Comment: @dumber_than_thou No problem, happy I was able to help!